# Encoded text conversion always fails

Tags: c++, c

```
int conv_utf8_to_ucs2(const char* src, size_t len)
{
    iconv_t cb = iconv_open("UTF-16", "UTF-8");
    if (cb == (iconv_t)(-1))
        return 0;

    uint16_t* outBuff = new uint16_t[len + 1];
    char* pout = (char*)outBuff;
    size_t inRemains = len;
    size_t outRemains = len * sizeof(uint16_t);

    printf("inRemains:%d outRemains:%d\n", (int)inRemains, (int)outRemains);

    size_t cvtlen = iconv(cb, &src, (size_t*)&inRemains, (char**)&pout, (size_t*)&outRemains);
    if (cvtlen == (size_t)-1) {
        //CONVERSION ALWAYS FAILS
        goto out;
    }
    *pout = 0;

    printf("inRemains:%d outRemains:%d cvtlen:%d\n", (int)inRemains, (int)outRemains, (int)cvtlen);

    for (int i = 0; (i < len) && outBuff[i]; i++)
        printf("0x%04x\n", outBuff[i]);

out:
    if (outBuff)
        delete[] outBuff;
    iconv_close(cb);

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     char utf8_str[] = "안녕 세상아?";
     int len = strlen(utf8_str);

     conv_utf8_to_ucs2(utf8_str, len);

     return 0;
}
```

I have this tiny program to convert a string of UTF8 to UTF16, but `iconv` function always returns -1. I debug to go into its implementation but could not find any hint. Could someone offer an insight into this libiconv usage ?

Comment: Are you sure that embedding the string like that is working as you would expect? I would verify the contents of that string to ensure it is encoding in UTF-8.

Comment: Why use any casts in `size_t cvtlen = iconv(cb, &src, (size_t*)&inRemains, (char**)&pout, (size_t*)&outRemains);` unless the prototype is missing?

Comment: Does even `char utf8_str[] = "abc";` work for you?

Comment: @chux, No it doesn't. And Guvante I don't know how to check for that.

Comment: @user0175554 - when you debug your application, inspect what `utf8_str` has in it by looking at the memory it points to.  If it isn't what you expect, then that's an additional problem you need to straighten out (given that you stated that "abc" doesn't work either).

Comment: "안녕 세상아?" may not be a UTF8 encoded string.  Suggest reporting `printf("%d %d %d %d\n", utf8_str[0], utf8_str[1], utf8_str[2], utf8_str[3]);`